# SQL Server - Grouping results on a weekly basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a novice with SQL and need some help!

I have two fields, MoveInDate and MoveOutDate, both of which are date fields. I want to generate a result that counts the number of move-ins and move-outs per week. The output should look something like this:

```
Week Start      Week End              Move-In-Count      Move-Out-Count

1/20/2014       1/26/2014                  0                    4

1/27/2014       2/2/2014                   1                    0
```

I am working on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429434/tsql-grouping-customer-orders-by-week

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this should work.

```
Select COUNT(Primary_Key) As MoveInCount

FROM [dbo].[tableName]

where MoveInDate between WeekStartDate and WeekEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Date Dimension since you are looking to group by week.

You can get a ready made date dimension here along with script to load into your database:

http://www.kimballgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Ch10-DateDim.xls

Once you have loaded your dimension you can group by Week and count by the number of move in, move out dates.