# Get new customers every week in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data related to customers and the number of transactions they perform every day. I would like to see how many "new" customers do we get each week. The data looks like the following:

```
Custnum    Created    Revenue
1    2014/10/23    30
4    2014/10/23    20
5    2014/10/23    40
2    2014/10/30    13
3    2014/10/30    45
1    2014/10/30    56
```

In the above (sample) data, we can see that customer with `custnum` 1 has transactions in consecutive weeks, I want only the new customers for the next week, ones that have never done business with us in the past. In other words, I want the number of totally new customers for each week. So the result should be:

```
CustCount    Created
3    2014/10/23
2    2014/10/30
```

I tried using the following query:

```
select 
    count(distinct custnum), 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, created), 0) as Date
from ORDERS
where created > '2013-01-01'
group by 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, created), 0)
order by
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, created), 0)
```

But this query gives me the number of unique customers each week, I want the number of new customers every week.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: One of the problems here is that you can't just rely on the previous week, as they may have been a customer but not had a purchase in 2 weeks.

Comment: [Grouping customer orders by week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429434/) might be usefull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### My understanding of your question

I took these statements:

- I would like to see how many "new" customers do we get each week.
- [customers] that have never done business with us in the past
- I want the number of totally new customers for each week

Do you want

```
 CustCount    Created
 2            week1    -- customer 1 and 2
 1            week2    -- customer 3
 2            week3    -- customer 4 and 5
 -- Option A
 1            week4    -- customer 6 is new and 2 was not counted 
 -- or Option B
 2            week4    -- customer 6 and 2; 
                       -- since customer 2 did not order anything in week3
```

#### Option A

This query `SELECT Custnum, DATEPART ( week , created) as WeekNumber from Revenues Order by Custnum` returns this output for the provided sample data

```
Custnum    WeekNumber 
1          31       -- counts
1          44       -- does not count, since customer already ordered once
2          36       -- counts
3          36       -- counts
3          44       -- does not count
4          43       -- counts
5          43       -- counts
5          45       -- does not count
```

#### First step: filter down the records

To get only the first record for a customer (the new customer) you can do this:

```
SELECT Distinct Custnum, Min(Created) as Min_Created 
FROM Revenues 
GROUP BY Custnum
```

#### Second step: Counting and Grouping by week

First i used the sql from [grouping customer orders by week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429434/), which you can find at the [old sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37b06/8) . But then i decided to use

```
Select Count(Custnum) as CountCust 
    , DATEPART(week, Min_Created) as Week_Min_Created 
FROM (
        SELECT Distinct Custnum, Min(Created) as Min_Created  
        FROM Revenues Group By Custnum
    ) sq Group by DATEPART(week, Min_Created)
```

On my [sql-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2) this returns

```
CountCust  Week_Min_Created
1          31    -- only customer 1
2          36    -- customer 2 and 3
2          43    -- customer 4 and 5
-- nothing for week 45 since customer 5 was already counted
```

#### Some sample data

This is the sample data i used

```
CREATE TABLE Revenues 
(
   Custnum int , 
   Created datetime,
   Revenue int 
);

INSERT INTO Revenues (Custnum, Created, Revenue)
VALUES
  (1, '20140801', 30),
  (2, '20140905', 13), (3, '20140905', 45),
  (4, '20141023', 20), (5, '20141023', 40),
  (3, '20141030', 45), (1, '20141030', 56),
  (5, '20141106', 60);
```

Comment: I want `Option A`, old customers shouldn't be counted at all. The SQLFiddle solution looks to be achieving `Option B`.

Comment: I copied your SQL `SELECT COUNT(Custnum)
 , dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20140105',Min_Created) / 7, '20140105') 
    AS WeekStart  
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
  Distinct Custnum
  , Min(Created) as Min_Created
 FROM Revenues
 Group By Custnum
) o
GROUP BY 
  dateadd(week, datediff(day,'20140105',Min_Created) / 7, '20140105'); ` and it does look correct to me. Thanks for being extremely helpful, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to work with a subset of ORDERS that only has each customer's first order date.

```
select 
    count(custnum), 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, created), 0) as Date
from
    (Select custnum, min(created) as created From Orders Group by custnum) o
where created > '2013-01-01'
group by 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, created), 0)
order by
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, created), 0)
```

Comment: how will he identify which customer is new?

Comment: @Bill - This query does give me some results, but I'm not entirely sure if they're correct. I don't really understand how this is calculating number of new customers.

Comment: @lookslikeanevo this line `Select custnum, min(created) as created` selects only the first record of a customer.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree thats in the subquery and not in the main query the output of the overal query is count of custnum and a date. The op is looking for new customers

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree meh - his expected (picutred output)results is different from how he worded it...not sure what he really wants ha

Comment: @lookslikeanevo According to my understanding the subquery does filter the records down to contain only the first transaction of the customer so this would be the new customer.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree - The subquery `Select custnum, min(created) as created From Orders Group by custnum` results in each customer number in column 1 and the first transaction date in column 2. This means that the dataset on which the outer query is supposed to execute, has been minimized to only the number of distinct customers. So how does the overall query result in the number of new customers each week when the dataset itself has been minimized? Does this make sense? The query actually returns some results, I'm just unsure if they're correct. I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Patthebug: It is unclear for me what you consider a new customer. I updated my answer to understand if you want `Option A` or `Option B`

Comment: @Bill - I just realized that your answer achieved exactly the same as 341613's answer. I wish I could accept two answers. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a where clause such that the custnum does not exist in before a week, something like

```
custnum not in (select custnum from orders where created < (start date of week))
```

Pseudo code since I am not really familiar with sql server functions

Answer (score 0):

A better design would be to store the date the customer signed up along with the rest of their information. 
Once that is done you can use the solution in the link below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2caaa/1